# Neo4j, SDN5 and index over Object field

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

I have the following SDN5 node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Value {

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Object value;

}
```

As you may see, I have defined `value` as `Object` and placed the index over it.

According to my application business logic, I'm putting different Java types into the `Value.value` like `String`, `Long`, `Double`, `Integer` etc. Taking this into account I wondering will the Neo4j index effectively work there? Does it make any sense there? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you anything about performance but it is technically possible to do this.

One idea that came to my mind to avoid mixed types in the database would be to use a converter for the property that does nothing more than `.toString()` and back (might be ugly code for the conversion back to Java and discard some types e.g. there will be no difference in `Double` and `Float`).

Answer (score 0):

Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays for node property.

Comment: Sorry but how does it answers the question?

Comment: I don’t use complex types these, only primitive box-versions and strings